# Having find() find more than once in regex in java

Tags: java, regex, find

I need find() to find more than once. For example, in the regex below it will only get "i am cool1", but I also want it to get "i am cool2" and "i am cool3". How would I do that?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("i am cool([0-9]{1})", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
String theString = "i am cool1 text i am cool2 text i am cool3 text";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(theString);
matcher.find();
whatYouNeed = matcher.group(1);
```

Comment: @user85421 rip. Isn't there a way to do this all at once?

Comment: This is unclear: your regex is `i am cool([0-9])`, and you get Group 1 value with `.group(1)`. However, you say *it will only get "i am cool1"*. Your code can't get that. So, what do you want to get in the end?

Answer (score 1):

You have to invoke find() for every match. You can get the whole match with group() (without index).

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("i am cool([0-9]{1})", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    String theString = "i am cool1 text i am cool2 text i am cool3 text";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(theString);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

This will print

```
i am cool1
i am cool2
i am cool3
```